# How to obtain a dataset that consists of observed and simulated survival data

Tags: r, simulation, survival-analysis

I would like to answer a certain question with a simulated data set of survival data. However, in order to make it as close to an existing situation as possible, I would like to start with some existing data.

Let's say I want to construct a data set of a randomized clinical trial with the following variables:

1. Subject ID
2. Treatment arm (0=placebo, 1=treated)
3. Survival time (continuous)
4. Survival censor indicator (1=death, 0=censored)
5. Sex (0=man, 1= woman)

I already have the following:

- A data set that contains the first 4 variables
- The distribution of sex (so the number of men and number of women in the study)
- The subgroup hazard ratio for treated vs placebo in men
- The subgroup hazard ratio for treated vs placebo in women

Does anybody have suggestions on how to add the variable sex to the dataset with survival times, in a way that corresponds with the known frequencies and subgroup hazard ratios?
It would be helpful if this would be possible for just the above simplified example, but ideally I would like to do this jointly for a couple of covariates (not just sex).

I'm hoping for a solution in R.

I have tried using sim.survdata, by tweaking the input so that the simulated data approximates my input described above, but I would rather start with the existing data so that it corresponds exactly to the existing data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?